# WordPress My Custom Class doesn't appear in inspection

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm editing my CSS and I have new Custom class  but it's not working and it is not showing in inspection either.
Normally when you have a class and this class is overriden, it shows in inspection so I don't believe this is a hierarchy problem

```
Style.css
.search-form .search-submit .mycustomclass{}
```

in my inspection i see

```
.search-form .search-submit{}
```

is loaded but that's it

Comment: are you trying to override your custom class to existing class:
.search-form .search-submit ?
then you have to use it like :
.search-form .search-submit.mycustomclass
remove space in between

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you are viewing cached version of your css, try removing your browser cached or try hard refresh by pressing `CTRL + F5`

hope it works for you.

Comment: nope it's not working in multiple browsers either. i changed my custom class to id and it doesnt work too it seems my changes in style file is not being loaded

Comment: thats why I told u to dump your cached as you are not getting latest version of your updated file, I suspect you are using some caching plugin in wordpress try to dump cached from the plugin interface

Comment: I'm not using any plugin yet, cache is cleared from chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Please check those steps to see if any of them may help you:

1. check if you are on the correct URL.
2. Clear your cache (especially if you use a CMS like Drupal).
3. On the Dev Tools (Google Chrome) go to `Sources`, find your CSS file
   and check if your class is listed on that file.
4. Try to make any other changes to the CSS file to see if it will
   take any changes at all. E.g. `body { display: none; }`

Comment: my class is in css file as you said in #3
changing display none works